# Haskell Noob: QuasiQuotes OverloadedStrings in Yesod not Working?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm not sure why I cant get this working....

I have QuasiQuotes and OverloadedStrings at the top of my hs file, at the top of main.hs, maindevel.hs and also declared in my foo.cabal file.

The ERROR:

```
Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Text’
    Expected type: Text
    Actual type: String
In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
    ‘renderHtml (GHC.Base.id (toHtml y))’
In the expression:
    putStrLn $ renderHtml (GHC.Base.id (toHtml y))
```

Code:

```
module Widgets.MainWidgets where
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}                      
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, TypeSynonymInstances, FlexibleInstances #-}
import Import

import Text.Hamlet (shamlet)
import Text.Blaze.Html.Renderer.String (renderHtml)
import Data.Char (toLower)
import Data.List (sort)
import qualified Data.Text    as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T

import ClassyPrelude
import Yesod
import Data.Time.Clock
import Data.Time.Calendar
import Data.Time.LocalTime
import Data.Time.Format

getCurrYear :: String
getCurrYear = formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%y" getCurrentTime

getYear :: IO ()
getYear = putStrLn $ renderHtml
    [shamlet|#{y}|]
        where y = getCurrYear
```

I also have this in my foo.cabal file:

```
extensions: TemplateHaskell
            QuasiQuotes
            OverloadedStrings
            NoImplicitPrelude
            CPP
            MultiParamTypeClasses
            TypeFamilies
            GADTs
            GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving
            FlexibleContexts
            EmptyDataDecls
            NoMonomorphismRestriction
            DeriveDataTypeable
            ViewPatterns
            TupleSections
            RecordWildCards
            TypeSynonymInstances
            FlexibleInstances
            DeriveGeneric
```

Any idea why I get the String/Text conversion error?
Thanks in advance!
Adrian

Comment: The OverloadedStrings extension makes string *literals* overloaded. It doesn't actually make String and Text the same type.

Comment: Ya... I do realize that... The issue is that I'm using code I lifted right out of a tutorial - and it works if I compile it separately . I think it has something to do with my imports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The putStrLn from ClassyPrelude takes a Text, not a String. The simplest solution would be to change the Renderer import to the Text version of the module.

Comment: Thanks I'll check that out - i'm thinning out my imports right now and will see what i'm actually doing with them ;)

Comment: Ive updated my code: removed classyprelude and put <span>#{y} in the shamlet instead of just #{y}.  
I added/changed these imports:
import Text.Blaze.Html.Renderer.Text (renderHtml)
import Data.Text (Text, append, pack)

Now i get this:
Couldn't match expected type ‘Text’
                with actual type ‘Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Text’
    NB: ‘Text’ is defined in ‘Data.Text.Internal’
        ‘Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Text’
          is defined in ‘Data.Text.Internal.Lazy’
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
      ‘renderHtml

Comment: This put me on the right path.  I have a lot to learn about Haskell types.  The learning curve is much higher than C for me! :)